# Passing parameters to the constructor of a Singleton

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var Database = (function(host, username, password, database) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: host,
        user: username,
        password: password,
        database: database
    });

    return {
        //all my functions
    };
}());
```

I am trying to make a Database singleton in node to communicate with my database.
But how to I pass the arguments, (host, username, password, database) into it when I call it?
I cant do:

```
var db = new Database(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

since database is a singleton...
Also, how do I make a constructor inside Database, and how do I pass arguments into it??

Answer (score 0):

The `()` on the final line is the list of arguments being passed to the function, and it is currently empty. Simply put your arguments there:

```
var Database = (function(host, username, password, database) {
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: host,
        user: username,
        password: password,
        database: database
    });

    return {
        //all my functions
    };
}(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE));
```

Comment: N.B.: after reading over your question again, I'm not 100% clear what you want. I'll leave this here in case it is helpful; if is not, I'll simply delete it.